# Get range of a sheet up to the last cell containing data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to select the range of 2 columns till the last row with a value. Now I use this code:

`var test = declSheet.getRange('Potjes!A:B');`

Form this sheet:

[image]

The result I get is this:

[image]

How can I select till the last row with value?

Comment: Do you want the headers in the selection>?  You only select the first two columns but a third is peeking out of the picture - are there values beyond that or do you ONLY want the first two columns? Please clarify your question - i.e. ignore all other columns (which it seems you wish based on your question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Sheet.getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) function which:

> Returns a Range corresponding to the dimensions in which data is
>   present.

It seems like you are only interested in column A and B so:

```
// var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var desiredRange = sheet.getRange("A1:B" + dataRange.getLastRow());
// desiredRange will consist of A1:B5 in OP example
```

Comment: This seems like the right direction i.e. not selecting the entire column, question remains is does the OP want the header or not.

Comment: Make the `dataRange.gelLastRow()` isolate to the columns.

Comment: I now use `var test = declSheet.getRange('Potjes!A2:B'+dataRangeTest.getLastRow());` works like a charm.